# Windows 10 refuses to install on certain drive

Tags: windows, boot, installation, ssd, sata

A couple days ago I bought new notebook without OS. At first I installed Windows 10 on stock HDD drive - everything went ok. Then I decided to replace it with with SSD from my old laptop which is Samsung 840 EVO and which were working fine for years. Now goes the bad part...

During windows installation I unable to format SSD disk drive with error code 0x80070057. The stock drive and another HDD drive have no this problem with same bios settings and same windows distributive. The SSD drive itself is fully workable on old laptop and able to format disk during installation without problem. Moreover: if install Windows 10 on SSD on old laptop and after that insert it into new laptop - I have message at boot "Disk read error. Press Ctrl-Alt-Delete...", but the same operation with HDD goes just fine and system loading ok.

So the short summary: all the disks has the same SATA interface and all of them working ok on old laptop, but one of them not working on new laptop. And questions are:

1. How is that possible?
2. How to fix this on new laptop?
3. Is that SSD problem or controller incompatibility?
4. May be I'm stupid somewhere?

For now, I have to use stock HDD drive which turns new laptop into a pumpkin ((

Comment: See this https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2476568/error-0x80070057-when-you-format-a-hard-disk-drive-to-install-windows-7

Comment: @Biswa already saw this, helps nothing - I've tried reformatting, cleaning and so on. It is not able to format disk on new laptop, but same operations works fine on old one.

Comment: *Is that SSD problem or controller incompatibility?* Unlikely since you are installing Windows 10.  This would be a problem, on older versions of Windows, like Windows 7.

Comment: @Ramhound what is your point? Windows 10 and Windows 7 is software, SSD and controller-related problem is hardware.

Comment: You asked if your SSD was incompatible with your system, my response to that specific question, no your system is compatiable.

Comment: @Ramhound, so may be I need to use some specific drivers for SSD, like Intel RST?